# Image gets blurry and zoomed out when erasing

Tags: ios, swift3, erase, cgpoint, uigraphicscontext

I am using functionality of erasing image and my code is like below. You can see  [Video HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/80l71wn65ui9o6f/Blurry.mov?dl=0). Here  `current_sticker_img` is my `Imageview`

**NOTE:** **I am also using Pan Gesture for zooming image**

```
 //MARK: Eraser touch event
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if btn_eraser.isSelected == true || btn_repaint.isSelected == true{
            let touch : UITouch = touches.first!
            lastpoint = touch.location(in: current_sticker_img)
        }
    }
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if btn_eraser.isSelected == true || btn_repaint.isSelected == true{
            let touch = touches.first!
            let currentPoint : CGPoint = touch.location(in: current_sticker_img)
            let isPointInsideView = current_sticker_img.point(inside: currentPoint, with: event)
            if isPointInsideView
            {
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(current_sticker_img.frame.size)
//                UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: (current_sticker_img.image?.size.width)!, height: (current_sticker_img.image?.size.height)!), false, (current_sticker_img.image?.scale)!)

                current_sticker_img
                    .image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (current_sticker_img.frame.size.width), height: (current_sticker_img.frame.size.height)))
                UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.setLineCap(.round)
                UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.setLineWidth(Current_slider_value_for_Eraser)

                UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.setShadow(offset: CGSize(width: CGFloat(0), height: CGFloat(0)), blur: 0, color: UIColor.clear.cgColor )
                UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.setBlendMode(.clear)

                UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.move(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(lastpoint.x), y: CGFloat(lastpoint.y)))
                UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(currentPoint.x), y: CGFloat(currentPoint.y)))
                UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.strokePath()

                current_sticker_img.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                lastpoint = currentPoint
            }
        }
    }
```

What I am doing wrong ? Please help me with it.
Thank you

Comment: And what your pan gesture related code does ?

Comment: @cire.boroguies just simple for zooming in and zooming out image

Comment: Ok but as your problem seems to be exactly related to the zoom out feature. Have you tried to use these delegate methods: func gesture​Recognizer(UIGesture​Recognizer, should​Recognize​Simultaneously​With:​ UIGesture​Recognizer)
or func gesture​Recognizer(UIGesture​Recognizer, should​Receive:​ UITouch) ? in order to make sure the pan gesture doesn't perform any action. And why are you using Pan Gesture for zooming and not Pinch Gesture ?

Comment: I am using this library https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/zdstickerview for it. This library give me all handling regarding to image. and in that image I used eraser

Comment: Have you try to set preventsResizing to YES on you StickerView just to be sure it doesn't come from this library ? Also could you log the image size of current_sticker_img.image before and juste after the                 current_sticker_img.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() line ?

Comment: No , I did not try prevent resizing and did not log currentimage.image but Sure I will try @cire.boroguies

Comment: I used preventresizing but same problem occurs, I dont want like that sticker will resize if user want to zoom in or out.